# No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory' Exception in DAO classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have an activity class that is annotated as a component that calls an action class:

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = NonRetryableException.class)
 public ExecuteTemplateResponse executeTemplate(ExecuteTemplateRequest request)
 {
      actionExecutionContext = action.execute(actionExecutionContext);
 }
```

My action class is also annotated with @Component and has the following execute method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
@Override
public ActionExecutionContext execute(ActionExecutionContext actionExecutionContext)
{
    iogl = ioglDao.create(iogl);
    return actionExecutionContext;
}
```

The ioglDao class is annotated as @Repository and has the following create method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
@Override
public InventoryOwnerGroupLocation create(InventoryOwnerGroupLocation iogl)
{
    // injected
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    session.save(iogl);

    return iogl;
}
```

I believe that the Transaction should propagate from the Service Layer to the dao class, but it seems it's not. I get the No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory' Exception.

Why isn't the transaction propagating to my DAO classes?

EDIT: added all of the activity class

```
@Service("FASelfServiceMappingService")
@Component
public class ExecuteTemplateActivity extends Activity
{
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExecuteTemplateActivity.class);


// mapper framework to interact with DynamoDB database
private final DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

// class to convert external models to internal models
private final InternalModelToDynamoDBModelConverter internalToDynamoDBConverter;
private final InternalModelToOracleModelConverter internalToOracleConverter;
private final CoralModelToInternalModelConverter coralToInternalConverter;

// class to generate list of actions
private final ActionGenerator actionGenerator;

// status constants
private static final String STATUS_COMPLETED = "COMPLETED";
private static final String STATUS_FAILED = "FAILED";

@Inject
public ExecuteTemplateActivity(InternalModelToDynamoDBModelConverter internalToDynamoDBConverter,
                               InternalModelToOracleModelConverter internalToOracleConverter,
                               CoralModelToInternalModelConverter coralToInternalConverter,
                               ActionGenerator actionGenerator,
                               DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper)
{
    this.internalToDynamoDBConverter = internalToDynamoDBConverter;
    this.internalToOracleConverter = internalToOracleConverter;
    this.coralToInternalConverter = coralToInternalConverter;
    this.actionGenerator = actionGenerator;
    this.dynamoDBMapper = dynamoDBMapper;
}


@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = NonRetryableException.class)
 @Operation("ExecuteTemplate")
 public ExecuteTemplateResponse executeTemplate(ExecuteTemplateRequest request) throws RetryableException, NonRetryableException
 {
     try
     {
         logger.info("Input given: " + request);

         // convert request input to an internal request
         Request internalRequest = coralToInternalConverter.coralRequestToInternal(request);
         logger.info("Successfully converted External Request to internal Request.");

         String templateName = getTemplateName(internalRequest);
         logger.info("Template Name extracted from the request: " + templateName);

         Template template = getTemplateFromDynamo(internalRequest, templateName);
         logger.info("Template read from dynamoDB table: " + template);

         // Generate a map from string to Action objects associated with the retrieved template
         List<Action> listOfActions = actionGenerator.generateActions(template.getActions());
         logger.info("Actions generated for template " + templateName + ": " + listOfActions);

         // Generate the action context for actions to pass to each other to keep track of state
         ActionExecutionContext actionExecutionContext = internalToOracleConverter.inputsToActionExecutionContext(internalRequest.getInputs());
        logger.info("Built ActionExecutionContext:" + actionExecutionContext);

         // execute the actions
         for (Action action : listOfActions)
         {
             actionExecutionContext = action.execute(actionExecutionContext);
         }
         logger.info("All actions executed successfully.");
         // request was completed successfully, create request in Request table
         String requestId = createRequestInDynamo(internalRequest, STATUS_COMPLETED);

         ExecuteTemplateResponse executeTemplateResponse = new ExecuteTemplateResponse();
         executeTemplateResponse.setRequestId(requestId);

         logger.info("Service call "+ this.getClass() +" succeeded.");
         return executeTemplateResponse;
         }
     catch (RetryableException re)
     {
         logger.error("Retryable Exception occurred in activity.", re);
         throw re;
     }
     catch (NonRetryableException nre)
     {
         logger.error("NonRetryable Exception occurred in activity.", nre);
         throw nre;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         logger.error("Unknown Exception occurred in activity.", e);
         throw new NonRetryableException("Unexpected error", e);
     }
 }

/**
 * extracts the templateName from the internalRequest
 * @param internalRequest internal model of the request
 * @return templateName
 */
private String getTemplateName(Request internalRequest)
{
    Validate.notNull(internalRequest, "internalRequest must not be null.");

    String templateName;
    try
    {
        // extract template name from request
        templateName = internalRequest.getTemplateName();
        Validate.notNull(templateName, "templateName must not be null.");
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException iae)
    {
        createRequestInDynamo(internalRequest, STATUS_FAILED);
        logger.error("Invalid input: templateName is null.");
        throw new NonRetryableException("Invalid input: templateName is null.", iae);
    }

    return templateName;
}

/**
 * Retrieves the template object associated with given templateName
 * @param internalRequest internal model of request
 * @param templateName name of template to retrieve
 * @return Template object
 */
private Template getTemplateFromDynamo(Request internalRequest, String templateName)
{
    Validate.notNull(internalRequest, "internalRequest must not be null.");
    Validate.notNull(templateName, "templateName must not be null.");

    Template template;
    try
    {
        // read the template with given template name from Templates table
        template = dynamoDBMapper.load(Template.class, templateName);
    }
    catch (DynamoDBMappingException ddbme)
    {
        createRequestInDynamo(internalRequest, STATUS_FAILED);
        logger.error("Reading template from dynamoDB table failed.", ddbme);
        throw new NonRetryableException("Incorrect class annotation or incompatible with class", ddbme);
    }
    catch (AmazonClientException ace)
    {
        createRequestInDynamo(internalRequest, STATUS_FAILED);
        logger.error("Reading template from dynamoDB table failed.", ace);
        throw new RetryableException("Error when loading template from dynamoDB", ace);
    }

    return template;
}
```

EDIT:

Transaction Manager configuration:

```
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"
                          mode="proxy" proxy-target-class='true' />

    <bean id="txManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Can you show more of your `activity` class (esp. the part, where you inject your action class)?

Comment: And also the part where you call the method executeTemplate. Do you call it from another class or from inside your activity class?

Comment: Added all of my activity class. I'm testing the activity class in a unit test and calling the executeTemplate from a unit test.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is maybe a problem related to your Spring configuration. Did you follow the guide at http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html? Can you show how you configure Spring transaction management ?

Comment: Yes, I followed the guide. I have updated the question with my Spring transaction management.

Comment: Thank you. Some more questions: does injection of sessionFactory in activity class work?  Is component scanning configured correctly (<context:component-scan base-package="com.youpackage..." />)? Since you already have '@Service', is the '@Component' annotation on the activity class necessary?

Comment: I have not tried injection of sessionFactory in the activity class as it's not needed there. It is injected directly into the DAO classes. Should I try that? Yes, component scanning is configured correctly. The @Service annotation on the activity class is from another internal framework, not spring.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exception with Spring WebFlux.

Issue :

```
repository.findByUserId(id);
```

Solution:

```
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

transactionTemplate.execute(transactionStatus -> identInformationRepository.findByUserId(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it can be solved with the following:

Try to separate the code from the transaction you are getting the error in, try to do the injection in a separate method, preferably at startup.

And add  @Transactional before begin void

Example:

BEFORE

```
public void mainProces(){
  System.out.println("Hello, i save my name");
  SQL(select)
  SQL(save)
}
```

AFTER

```
@Transactional
    public void secondProces(){
            SQL(save)
    }

public void mainProces(){
  System.out.println("Hello, i save my name");
  secondProces();
  SQL(select)
}
```